# How could we connect ODBC to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: connection, database

Is there any way to connect to a MS **ODBC** system to the linux os. Or there any other local database available for linux ? Or should we create database in the terminal itself ?

Comment: Example: http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/getting-started.html or https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568454%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.  Via unixODBC you can connect to multiple databases on your network (Access, MSSQL, Mysql, Oracle,...).  They may reside on your own computer as well as on remote computers (be it under windows or linux).
Have a look at [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/)